# Can I optimize this perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match some ip names (dotted decimal or names). I need to match any of the following:

```
hostname-1-2-3
hostname-1-2-3.here.somewhere.com
hostname-1-2-3.here or
192.168.1.2
hostname-1-2.*
```

I have this if statement:

```
if ($name !~ m/^[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+$/ and 
    not $name =~ m/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\.\*/ and 
    not $name =~ m/^[0-0]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)
{
    print "inside if\n";
}
else {
    print "inside else\n";
}
```

It now prints 'inside else' for the first 4 names, and 'inside if' for the last name (that name would be expanded in the code to several host names.

This is the behavior I want, I am just wondering if my regex could be combined since the first two matches are very similar.

Comment: what is the point make many tests on hostnames, and allows ip like `666.666.666.666`? why not check simple for the presence of the `*`?

Comment: how fast do you need it to be?  if it's not too slow, leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing too many negations here... It's not easy to read like that.

Here's a solution for you:

```
^(?:
    (?:\d+\.){3}\d+
    |
    [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9.]*
)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP9aH7/2)

This regex will match:

- IP addresses of the form ##.##.##.## (4 numbers, no less, no more)
- An address (letters, digits, dashes and dots) starting with a letter

I think that this should satisfy the same requirements.

Comment: \d is not a replacement for [0-9]; they mean quite different things.

Comment: @ysth They mean the same when used with the `a` (ASCII) regex modifier ([docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Digits)).